# Reference Request: Dirichlet operators with singular coefficients

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Let $d\geq 2$, $\delta \in (0,1)$ and let $\mathcal{L}_{d,\delta}$ be the second order differential operator defined by
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_{d,\delta}(f)(x) = \Delta(f)(x)-\delta \|x\|^{\delta-2}\langle x;\nabla(f)(x)\rangle.
\end{align*}
Consider the weak formulation problem in $L^2(\mu_\delta)$:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_{d,\delta}(f) = g
\end{align*}
for some data $g \in L^2(\mu_\delta)$ such that
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g(x) \mu_\delta(dx) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g(x) \exp\left(-\|x\|^{\delta}\right) dx = 0.
\end{align*}
What can be said about the solution $f$ (if it exists) of such a weak formulation problem? I am looking for any references regarding this type of PDE with singular coefficients. Note that you don't have Poincaré inequality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use spherical harmonic and blow up analysis to get results in various weighted spaces.

Comment: see this paper for the methods  The Supercritical Lane–Emden–Fowler Equation in Exterior Domains
Juan Dávila,Manuel del Pino  & Monica Musso (this is where I learned these techniques from)